# MS Access linked tables different for each user

Tags: database, ms-access, hyperlink, linker

I have a database that i have split into 3 pieces: a Front End, and two back ends that contain tables.  Copying the front end to a users desktop cuts the runtime from 90 minutes to 30 minutes. However, when I move the back end to the desktop as well, the runtime is less than 8 minutes.  The problem I am facing doing this is that I had to manually update the table links.

Is there a way to make it so that Access automatically updates the links based on what users computer it is on?

For example, I created a batch file to move the database files from the shared drive to a folder on the users destop using:

"%userprofile%\Desktop\Folder1\"

as the location to move the files to. "The "%userprofile%" automatically identifies the user and route the files properly. I didn't know if there was something similar to automatically update the links in Access.

Please let me know if you don't understand what I am trying to ask.

Comment: Are the two back end databases shared among multiple users?  What does the "run time?" mean?  Are you running a batch process?

Comment: Is this what you're doing?: 1.) copy db file from share to local drive 2.) do your data processing 3.) copy local db back to shared drive

Comment: HansUp, that is what I am doing.

Comment: Robert, all pieces of this database are used by multiple users, but not at the same time. The database is used once daily, but it's a different user almost every day. By run time I mean how long it takes the macro to run through all of the queries.  the batch process just moves the database from the shared drive to the desktop of the user.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the 1st backend is on the user computer, and the 2nd backend is on the shared network, I think what you can do is create a qry upon opening the database to update the user's table, then after exiting, a 2nd qry that will export user's table back to the 2nd backend on the shared network. You'll have to add a field in the table so that your database knows which record to be added or to be exported.